# Summing a field without placing it in group by in a select query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

As shown at table below

```
id  invoice_id   item_id     cost     price      quantity
1     1            1         32.00   35.00       5
2     2            1         32.00   35.00       6
3     4            2         43.00   52.00       8
```

i'd like to group it by it's item_id, cost, price , while summing the quantity

I've tried this

```
select item_id, cost,price, sum(quantity)
from table
group by item_id, cost,price,quantity
```

but this won't sum the quantity, but instead group it separately

I'd like to come up with this result

```
item_id     cost     price      quantity
  1         32.00   35.00        11
  2         43.00   52.00        8
```

Removing quantity from group by will display this error

```
i've tried that , this error shows, "Column 'XXXX.quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
"
```

Comment: Remove `quantity` from the `group by`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan : this error will show  "Column 'XXXX.quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
"

Comment: Are you showing us the actual query? I think you mistyped something, or removing quantity from the group by would be just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a windowed `SUM` instead of a `GROUP BY`

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

    CREATE TABLE #temp (
    id INT,
    invoice_id INT,
    item_id INT,
    cost FLOAT,
    price FLOAT,
    quantity INT);


    INSERT INTO #temp
            ( id
            ,invoice_id
            ,item_id
            ,cost
            ,price
            ,quantity
            )
    VALUES
            (1,1,1,32.00,35.00,5),
            (2,2,1,32.00,35.00,6),
            (3,4,2,43.00,52.00,8);


    SELECT DISTINCT
        item_id
        ,cost
        ,price
        ,SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id, cost, price) Sum
    FROM #temp



item_id     cost                   price                  Sum
----------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -----------
1           32                     35                     11
2           43                     52                     8
```

Or if you want to include `quantity` as well:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        item_id
        ,cost
        ,price
        ,quantity
        ,SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id, cost, price) Sum
    FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leave `quantity` out of the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
select item_id, cost, price, sum(quantity)
from table
group by item_id, cost, price
```

Comment: i've tried that , this error shows, "Column 'XXXX.quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
"

Comment: Well, that's... weird. The SUM() is an aggregate function. Double check.

Comment: @marlonpd This is because you are propably including `quantity` in the `SELECT` clause. `quantity` should only appear within the `sum` aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Quantity from your `group by` clause
as you are also grouping the quantity

> Group By clause doesnot include the fields which are being aggregated